# SVN Commit Dialog does not complete. i see the commits propagate to server but the dialog does include committed revision and successful message

Tags: svn, version-control

Svn commit on specific repository does not show successful message in commit dialog instead the commit dialog hangs on "committing transaction" this happens to only specific repository, I have updated the repo permission of this repo in server also did a svn verify to find if there is any corrupt revisions.

(svn client 1.9.7, server - 1.8.15)

[image: Commit dialog image attached]

Has anyone experienced similar behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks necessary details to get a precise answer. However, I can guess several potential root causes:

- the affected repository has a pre-commit hook script that hangs and prevents the transaction from being promoted to a new revision.
- there is some antivirus on the server side that interferes with SVN server operations.

Comment: yeah, found out that the postcommit hook had an entry at the end of the file  "vi post-commit " which was not letting the exit of dialog with successful message